# Pythonic way of replacing nan sub-array with array of same size

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have given a `numpy` array like this:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 5, np.nan, 6, np.nan])
# [1, 2, 3, 4, nan, 5, nan, 6, nan]
```

I know the number of `nan` values in the array and have the according array for replacement, e.g.:

```
b = np.array([12, 13, 14])
# [12, 13, 14]
```

What is the pythonic way of substituting the array `b` for all the `nan` value, such that I get the reult:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 5, 13, 6, 14]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perform boolean indexing on `a` using `np.isnan` and replace with `b` as:

```
a[np.isnan(a)] = b
```

---

```
print(a)
# array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4., 12.,  5., 13.,  6., 14.])
```

Comment: I'll just add this as a reference https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html to emphasize that `np.isnan` is probably *the* way to do it, as `np.nan == np.nan` is always `False`.